# Dividing Lines --HTML

Tags: css, html

How do I place down a dividing vertical line on a webpage in HTML/CSS that will constantly stay centered, regardless of how wide the browser window is at a given time?

Comment: What do you mean by _dividing line_? You can add a pseudo element to the `body` tag to create a center vertical line - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sfeonog/1)

Comment: there are numerous ways to achieve what you want depending on the scenario and you can also have look at [Column Count](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp), place `column-count: 2` and `column-width: 50%`

Comment: Or put two `inline-block` divs and give one some border - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sfeonog/2/).

Comment: ya actually inline-block is more better as column count is not supported below Internet Explorer 10

Comment: @Vucko how do I add a pseudo-element?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about a border.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#a {
    background-color: yellow;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

#b {
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: to be more precise the css for `div` should contain `width: 50%`

Comment: There is no simple element for vertical lines like the `<hr>` tag for horizontal lines.  When you see a vertical line, it is a `border` or a `column-count` property.